# schtasks returns error 5 with admin rights

Tags: java, windows, scheduled-tasks, administrator, windows-task-scheduler

I have been trying to execute this short code as Administrator with PowerShell and CMD but I got the same result with error 5.

Code:

```java
String createTask = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\schtasks.exe /Create /SC ONSTART /TN \"Test\" /TR \"java -jar \\\"C:\\Users\\Christophe Rillos\\Desktop\\Test.jar\\\"\"";
try
{
    System.out.println(createTask);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(createTask);
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\ProgramData\AltisCraft.fr> java -jar .\j.jar
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /Create /SC ONSTART /TN "Test" /TR "java -jar \"C:\Users\Christophe Rillos\Desktop\Test.jar\""
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe": CreateProcess error=5, Access denied
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access denied
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: `schtask.exe /create` is an incomplete statement that fails with error code 0x80004005 when run in CMD.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Post updated.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run the `schtasks` statement directly in the same PowerShell or CMD window?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers PowerShell (Admin):
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /Create /SC ONSTART /TN "Test" /TR "java -jar \"C:\Users\Christ
ophe Rillos\Desktop\Test.jar\""
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "Test" has successfully been created. and same with CMD (Admin)

Comment: Then it looks to me like your Java program doesn't inherit the UAC admin token from its parent process.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes I thinked about it but I think I got the same error with executing a .exe with admin rights by using launch4j, any idea ?